# Водяной знак для fancybox

Tags: jquery

Как сделать водяной знак на фотографиях в галереии **fancybox**

Comment: изменить через javascript сами изображения не получиться, эти действия нужно производить с серверной стороны. Максимум что можно это накладывать сверху изображения html блок содержащий полупрозрачное изображение, это будет создавать видимость водного знака, но если кто то сохранит изображение он увидит что водного знака нет.

Comment: ну или если вариант с серверной частью не подходит, можно пересохранить все изображения с водяным знаком.

Comment: Если изображения я пересохраню, то я не смогу поменять водяные знаки, если вдруг захочется. Нужно решение динамически менять водяной знак

Comment: Тогда у вас нет выбора: вы можете делать это только на сервере. Возможно, можно как-то дорисовывать через canvas, но это всё равно будет не то: любой всё равно сможет загрузить исходное изображение.

Comment: Позвольте поинтересоваться, а смысл тогда в этом водяном знаке если он будет генерится на javascript ?

Answer (score 2):

Соглашусь с предыдушим, на  fancybox сделать получится только поверхностным наложением полупрозрачной картинки, это сделать просто. но если сохранить изображение на комп, то оно будет чистое, без водяного знака.

как делал я.
на сервере делал **mod_rewrite** ко всем изображениям, тоесть при обращении к картинке - обращались к **php** скрипту, который брал эту рактинку и заранее сделанный водяной знак, у меня он был в png, и накладывал одно на другое.

тоесть заметно не было что идет обращение к какому то скрипту, а просто загруузка иде картинки с водяным знаком.

ПЛЮС - этого метода что можно легко менять водяной знак, т.к. картинка не редактируется фактически
МИНУС - это нагрузка на сервер при каждом обращении к картинке (но тут можно кешировать и нагрузка снизится в разы )